# Download and view PDF File in app android

Tags: android, pdf, url, view, download

I want to create an application that will  download and automatically open PDF files after the download is complete within the application.
But I'm still  IT student and I don't have much experience and After a long search, I found this
https://github.com/thugzook/PDF_Downloader

**My problem**
When the Internet is cut off when downloading, the application reopens, the download does not resume after the Internet is restored, and a blank pdf view page opens without completing the download.
**Please help me.**

**Main.java**

public class Main AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button pdfButton = findViewById(R.id.button1);

    pdfButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, pdfView.class);

            //pass the URL and filename to pdfView
            intent.putExtra("File URL", "https://maven.apache.org/archives/maven-1.x/maven.pdf");
            intent.putExtra ("File Name", "finalfinal.pdf");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

**Downloader.java**

public class Downloader {

```
/*** THIS VERSION GOES AROUND THE ASYNCEVENT REQUIREMENT WITH CHANGING THE SDK'S THREAD POLICY ***/
public static void DownloadFile(String fileURL, File directory) {
    try {
        //Circumvents the async requirement needed by higher build versions.
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy =
                    new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(directory);
        URL u = new URL(fileURL);
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        c.connect();
        InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

        //Read bytes of the file
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int len1 = 0;
        while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
        }
        f.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

**pdfView.java**

public class pdfView extends AppCompatActivity {

```
PDFView pdfView; //pdfView object
String URL;
String fileName;
File directory; //path of created File

// Container for all parameters of DownloadAsync
private static class AsyncParameters {
    String URL;
    File directory;
    AsyncParameters(String URL, File directory) {
        this.URL = URL;
        this.directory = directory;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf_view);

    //Grab the extras from the intent call
    Intent intent = getIntent(); //whatever calls this activity, gather the intent
    URL = intent.getStringExtra("File URL"); // in this case, get the file name of the "extra" passed through
    fileName = intent.getStringExtra("File Name");

    //Grab the internal storage directory and create a folder if it doesn't exist
    File intDirectory = getFilesDir();
    File folder = new File(intDirectory, "pdf");
    boolean isDirectoryCreated = folder.exists();

    //See if the file exists
    if (!isDirectoryCreated) {
        isDirectoryCreated= folder.mkdir();
    }
    if(isDirectoryCreated) {
        directory = new File(folder, fileName);
        try {
            directory.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        //See if file already exists (reduces wait time)
        boolean empty = directory.length() == 0;
        if (empty) {
            /**Call class to create parameter container **/
            AsyncParameters param = new AsyncParameters(URL, directory);
            DownloadAsync Downloader = new DownloadAsync();
            Downloader.execute(param);
        }
            showPdf();
    }

}
/**class for library showPdf**/
public void showPdf()
{
    pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
    pdfView.fromFile(directory).load();
}

/**Class for asynchronous tasks**/
public class DownloadAsync extends AsyncTask<AsyncParameters, Void, Void> {

    // Container for all parameters of DownloadAsync
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Create a progress bar that details the program downloading
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(pdfView.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Downloading Database...");
        String message= "Downloading Files";

        SpannableString ss2 =  new SpannableString(message);
        ss2.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0, ss2.length(), 0);
        ss2.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, ss2.length(), 0);

        pDialog.setMessage(ss2);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(AsyncParameters... params) {
        /**grab the container AsyncParameters and the values within it**/
        String fileURL = params[0].URL;
        File directory = params[0].directory;
        try {
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(directory);
            java.net.URL u = new URL(fileURL);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.connect();
            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            f.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            pDialog.setMessage(new SpannableString("ERROR DOWNLOADING"));
        }
        onPostExecute();
        return null;
    }

    private void onPostExecute() {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        showPdf();
    }
}
```

}

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".pdfView"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: `onPostExecute();` Remove that line.

Comment: `When the Internet is cut off when downloading, the application reopens,` That is hard to believe.

Comment: I want when I click the download button again after I stop the download the download restarts and ProgressDialog appears again

Comment: If you can help me, I will be grateful to you

Comment: You did not react to my comments. What am i doing here!?